# Title column of Event does not show the JSON formatting in a Calendar List in 365

Tags: json, formatting, sharepoint-online

I am trying to change the background color of the calendar entries based on a choice column "OOOType" (internal name) that can have the values: 'Vacation' ,'Out of Office', 'Business Travel'

I want: 
'Vacation' to show in green,'Out of Office' in plum,  'Business Travel' in bisque

I added JSON formatting to the title column of the calendar list.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
      "background-color": "=if([$OOOType] == 'Vacation', 'green',if([$OOOType] == 'Out of Office', 'plum',if([$OOOType] == 'Business Travel', 'bisque', '')))"
    }
}
```

The calendar shows the entries in the normal color of the theme. 
The formatting does not take.

Also the Chrome console shows the error:
Exception while trying to access stylesheet rules: SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules init.js:1

and

Cannot find theme color: Light1     theming.js:1

Tested on generic list (not Calendar) and it works right.
Turns out that is the issue. 
Microsoft pleas help :-)

Comment: are you using a custom list or calendar app? If you are using calendar app I don't think modern formatting will work on this as everything in the calendar app is classic.

Comment: I found out how to do it on any calendar. thanks